# In Visual Studio, how can I filter the auto-complete so it doesn't display the extension method and display native members only?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, autocomplete

If I have a

```
List<string> x;
```

When I write `x.` the auto-complete dialog will open and it will display a lot of linq methods and so its hard for me to find the methods that are native to the `List<T>`.

Is there a way to temporarily let the auto-complete not display the linq extention methods?

Right now I am using the method of removing the `using System.Linq;` but I was looking into a more efficient way.

thanks

Comment: They are visibly different, extension methods (all static methods really) have a little blue decoration on them.

Comment: @R0MANARMY: the problem is not that i dont see them , the problem is that there is a lot of them and so i cant find the normal functions because of the noise

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/657573/vs-intellisense-can-you-hide-extension-methods

Comment: @Stephen McDaniel: you are right, too bad i didnt see this question, i would have known that there is no solution to this problem before seting a bounty :)

Answer (score 1):

You could alias the `System.Linq` namespace in your using:

```
using AliasLinq = System.Linq;
```

That way, none of the Linq stuff will show up unless you first type `AliasLinq.`

Comment: i dont understand. what will this do?

Comment: Surprisingly this works. Though how do you call the extension methods if you do need to use them? I wish there were a key-combo...

Comment: yeah but this dont solve anything , now any .linq extention method dont work. unless i type it as AliasLinq.Enumrable..... . i just wanted it not be shown in the list but if any method is written it should work.