# How to extend method from parent and child with the same name

Tags: c#, inheritance, extension-methods

First code sample:

```
public class Parent
{

}

public static class ParentExtension
{
    public static void DoSomething<T>(this T element) where T : Parent
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class Child : Parent
{

}
public static class ChildExtension
{
    public static void DoSomething<T>(this T element) where T : Child
    {
        ...
    }
}
//Trying to call child extension class
var child = new Child();
child.DoSomething(); //Actually calls the parent extension method even though it is a child class
```

So, is it possible to accomplish what I am doing here? 
I assumed that the most specific extension would be picked up, but that is clearly not the case.

Comment: If you want it to call the parent extension method, why does the child one even exist??

Comment: This may clarify things for you: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature/

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31788804/how-to-hide-extension-methods-from-derived-classes?rq=1) seems relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the generic parameter :

```
public static class ParentExtension
{
    public static void DoSomething(this Parent element)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
public static class ChildExtension
{
    public static void DoSomething(this Child element)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Note: `void ChildExtension::DoSomething(this Child element)` will be called, as `Child` is more specific than `Parent`.

---

Or... This is going to look ugly and defeat the purpose of having the extension method :

```
// Invoke the method explicitly
ParentExtension.DoSomething(child);
ChildExtension.DoSomething(child);
```

Comment: This solved my issue, but would it be possible to call the parent extension method from the child one?

Comment: @YannThibodeau In the child extension's body, add`ParentExtension.DoSomething(element);` where appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for filling my lack of knowledge, cheers. Worked perfectly. Didn't you could call extension methods like this.

Comment: ["Extension methods are a special kind of static method, but they are called as if they were instance methods on the extended type."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/bb383977.aspx) It is just c# syntax sugar.